# Display details fragment when screen orientation changes to portrait

Tags: android

I'm new to fragments and my app contains a single frame layout that shows a list of options in portrait mode and in landscape shows a combination of list view in the left pane and the details of the selected option in the right pane.

On top of the screen, I have a header having images like logout, page title.

When I change the screen's orientation from landscape to portrait, I always see the list view appearing but with the header details from the landscape mode screen.

My question is how could I display the details fragment instead of list fragment while screen orientation changes from landscape to portrait?

Also, i got a java.lang.RuntimeException like: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'. To get rid of it, i placed a dummy listview and set its visibility to gone. Now its working fine,but is it a good practice ? and why I'm getting this exception?

Comment: Did you solve it. Either post you answer or mark the existing answer as accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dual Pane Layout you need to implement Just check for example that your layout contain detail fragment or not if contains then show detail here.

```
   View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);
    mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
```

See details article [Displaying Fragment Inside Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)